# JSON issue with looping inside closure

Tags: json, swift, loops, closures

I have to pull JSON data from a few different website endpoints in order to get a full view of the objects I'm working with. In order to do so, I am using the downloadJSON code below. This works OK, except whenever I create a for loop within downloadJSON(){   }, the amount of iterations in the loop seems to be multiplied by the count in the endpoints array.

For instance, I'm getting a length of 15 for array1 rather than length 5, which is what I would expect, since there are 5 objects in dataSet1.

Could you explain why this is occurring, and what could be done to rectify the issue? Also, I am doing a lot of my data manipulation within downloadJSON(){   }, so if that is the wrong spot, that would be helpful to know.

Below is a generalized version of the code I am using.

Thank you in advance.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBar: UITabBarController {

let website = "https://www.website.com/"
let endpoints = ["endpoint1","endpoint2","endpoint3"]
var objects = ["obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5"]

var dataSet1 = [Struct1]()
var dataSet2 = [Struct1]()
var dataSet3 = [Struct1]()

var array1 = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tab1 = OverallViewController(nibName: "OverallViewController", bundle: nil)
    tab1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Overall", image: UIImage(named: "overallIcon"), tag: 1)

    viewControllers = [tab1]

    downloadJSON() {

        for i in 0..<self.dataSet1.count {
                self.array1.append(i)
        }

        tab1.dataSet1 = self.dataSet1
        tab1.dataSet2 = self.dataSet2
        tab1.dataSet3 = self.dataSet3
        tab1.array1 = self.array1

        tab1.overallView.reloadData()
    }
}

func downloadJSON( completed:@escaping ()->()){

    var data1 = [Struct1]()
    var data2 = [Struct1]()
    var data3 = [Struct1]()

    for j in 0..<objects.count {
    for i in 0..<endpoints.count {

        guard let qurl = URL(string: website + endpoints[i] + objects[j]) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: qurl) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                do{
                    switch i {
                    case 0:
                        data1 = try JSONDecoder().decode([Struct1].self, from: data!)
                        self.dataSet1 = data1 + self.dataSet1
                    case 1:
                        data2 = try JSONDecoder().decode([Struct1].self, from: data!)
                        self.dataSet2 = data2 + self.dataSet2
                    default:
                        data3 = try JSONDecoder().decode([Struct1].self, from: data!)
                        self.dataSet3 = data3 + self.dataSet3

                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{ completed() }
                } catch { print("JSON Error") }
            }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For each end point, create a `Operation`.  Make one extra `Operation` which is dependent on all the other operations completing.  Put it all into a `OperationQueue` and them run.  The last `Operation` (with all the dependencies) will wait to all the others have completed and then you can can `completed` ... as a over simplistic, high level concept

Comment: Your *generalized version of the code* is a bit confusing because there is actually only **one** object in `objects`

Comment: @vadian I do agree it is confusing. Since the objects are separated by commas, the URL will return a JSON string with members for each of the 5 objects, which can then be decoded.

Comment: There aren't 5 objects, there is *one* string, count the double quotes.

Comment: Right, that is what I meant. Here is the actual URL, its purpose is to generate the JSON string which can then be decoded. https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/stats?symbols=AAPL,AET,AIG,AMAT,AXP